# What are the secure session management mechanisms other than cookies?

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies

For a web application, what are the secure session management mechanisms  available. I know a few. But would like to research on all available mechanisms.

I found a web application which works strictly on IE9 and above.It was allotted to me for testing purpose (and so I cant reveal the url or details). The wb application installed some software on the computer upon login and then only we can use the website. If we log in to the web application it opens in a new IE window which has no other buttons (settings,bookmarks or anything) or address bar. When I intercepted the traffic with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), I found that no cookies are being set during the log in time. I was curious how they manage sessions without cookies.

This is the base of my research. So any input, like names of secure session management mechanisms or any links can be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the JSON Web Token and store it using something like [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) or [store.js](https://github.com/marcuswestin/store.js/), so it should be available in the new opened IE window.